# How do I set the IP / port for the Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

```
$ kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://192.168.1.32:6443
  name: kubernetes
```

How can I set the IP address / Port of the actual **cluster**? Why is this default set?

I'm not trying to change the 'client' IP/port.

I've tried: `sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr="192.168.0.0/16"  --apiserver-advertise-address 192.168.99.100 --apiserver-bind-port 8443` which just seems to hang on:

```
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.9.3
[init] Using Authorization modes: [Node RBAC]
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
    [WARNING FileExisting-crictl]: crictl not found in system path
[preflight] Starting the kubelet service
[certificates] Generated ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated apiserver certificate and key.
[certificates] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [diy-virtual-machine kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.96.0.1 192.168.99.100]
[certificates] Generated apiserver-kubelet-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated sa key and public key.
[certificates] Generated front-proxy-ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated front-proxy-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Valid certificates and keys now exist in "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "admin.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "kubelet.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "controller-manager.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "scheduler.conf"
[controlplane] Wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-apiserver to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml"
[controlplane] Wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-controller-manager to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml"
[controlplane] Wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-scheduler to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml"
[etcd] Wrote Static Pod manifest for a local etcd instance to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml"
[init] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as Static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests".
[init] This might take a minute or longer if the control plane images have to be pulled.
```

Comment: Hi,  `--apiserver-advertise-address string ` the value needs to be a string  here. Therefore, `--apiserver-advertise-address "192.168.99.100"` will not hang.

Comment: If you use google cloud platform i can post answer with instructions, about how to create load balancer with external ip and forward all traffic through it

Comment: Hi @Chris, did it solve your issue? k8s API Server takes the default network interface for IP address.

Comment: Not sure, I abandoned this idea. Thanks for the help.

Comment: alright, I have answered the issue. Could you please close the question. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> --apiserver-advertise-address **string**      The IP address the API Server will advertise it's listening on. Specify '0.0.0.0' to use the address of the default network interface.

by providing specific IP with flags It will take the designated IP and Port respectively. 
For example

```
--apiserver-advertise-address "192.168.99.100"
--apiserver-bind-port 8443
```

Reference:

[kubeadm-config flags](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-config/#cmd-config-from-flags)